# Flask OIDC: oauth2client.client.FlowExchangeError

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

**The Problem:**

The library [flask-oidc](https://github.com/puiterwijk/flask-oidc/) includes the `scope` parameter into the authorization-code/access-token exchange request, which unsurprisingly throws the following error:

> oauth2client.client.FlowExchangeError: invalid_request Scope parameter is not supported on an authorization code access_token exchange request. Scope parameter should be supplied to the authorized request.

**The Question:**

Is this a configuration problem or a library problem?

**My Configurations:**

- Flask Application:

```py
app.config.update({
    'DEBUG': True,
    'TESTING': True,
    'SECRET_KEY': 'secret',
    'SERVER_NAME' : 'flask.example.com:8000',
    'OIDC_COOKIE_SECURE': False,
    'OIDC_REQUIRE_VERIFIED_EMAIL': False,
    'OIDC_CALLBACK_ROUTE': '/oidc/callback',
    'OIDC_CLIENT_SECRETS': 'client_secrets.json'
})
oidc = OpenIDConnect(app)
```

- client_secrets.json

```json
{
    "web": {
        "auth_uri": "http://openam.example.com:8080/openam/oauth2/realms/root/authorize",
        "issuer": "http://openam.example.com:8080/openam/oauth2/realms/root/",
        "userinfo_uri": "http://openam.example.com:8080/openam/oauth2/realms/root/userinfo",
        "client_id": "MyClientID",
        "client_secret": "password",
        "redirect_uris": [
            "http://flask.example.com:8000/oidc/callback"
        ],
        "token_uri": "http://openam.example.com:8080/openam/oauth2/realms/root/token",
        "token_introspection_uri": "http://openam.example.com:8080/openam/oauth2/realms/root/introspect"
    }
}
```

- Access Manager

For the access manager I use [OpenAM](https://github.com/OpenIdentityPlatform/OpenAM). I configured an OpenAM client agent as follows:

- Client ID = `MyClientID`
- Client Secret = `password`
- Response Type = `code`
- Token Endpoint Authentication Method = `client_secret_post`
- Redirect URI = `http://flask.example.com:8000/oidc/callback`

**Context**:
I use [flask-oidc](https://github.com/puiterwijk/flask-oidc/) for the logic on the application side and [OpenAM](https://github.com/OpenIdentityPlatform/OpenAM) for the identity and access management - both applications run in docker containers. When using simple curl commands I can retrieve an authorization grant as well as an authentication token (grant type: Authorization Code Grant). However, using the mentioned library, after logging in to OpenAM and granting authorization to the application (endpoint 'oauth2/authorize'), flask-oidc sends the following GET request:

```
GET /oidc/callback?code=<some code> \
&scope=openid%20email \
&iss=http%3A%2F%2Fopenam.example.com%3A8080%2Fopenam%2Foauth2 \
&state=<some state> \
&client_id=MyClientID
```

Which leads to the error mentioned above.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: In my version of the error I don't even see a scope in the request http://127.0.0.1:5000/oidc_callback?code=zysd2I9qMpQBpXse1MgBB-_hI9U&iss=https%3A%2F%2Flogin-at.dts.utah.gov%3A443%2Fsso%2Foauth2&state=<some state>

Comment: Not answer to the original problem, but it looks like the flask-oidc library is not maintained, and it uses the deprecated oauth2client lib. Maybe switching to something like https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ would solve the problem?

Comment: @bartcubrich sadly I did not.

Comment: @Michal Trojanowski, I think this could be the only answer if that is teh case, as it is actually the oath2 library that is throwing the error. Does python-social-auth support OIDC?

Answer (score 2):

While this does not directly answer the question, the best answer I could find was to use pyJWT or oauthlib instead of using flask-oidc. I found pyjwt was very straightforward in most respects, and there is an excellent tutorial here:

[SSO Using Flask Request Oauthlib and pyjwt](https://papyrus.so/@digitalmeadow/%5Bpython%5D-sso-using-flask,-requests-oauthlib-and-pyjwt)

I am not sure of this, but because the error is generated by oauth2client, not flask-oidc, it is possible the error is actually just related to the deprecated oathlib2clientlib.

There was a detailed request to [mark the entire flask-oidc project as deprecated](https://github.com/puiterwijk/flask-oidc/issues/85), but that request was made several years after the flask-oidc project was stopped being maintained. I hope one day flask will roove this link from their site because it is misleading to think that it is a main part of flask.